# CakePHP installation seems to be not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I got to this page in the CakePHP setup instructions: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1536/Creating-Post-Views

So basically I just created a model, controller and view.  Then the instructions say to go to http://www.problemio.com/problems/index because instead of their examples with posts, I use "problems"

My setup is like this: rootDirectory/cakephp/app/views/problems/index.ctp

According to the instructions, it should find that index page, but somehow it doesn't.

Is there something I am doing totally wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried: `http://www.problemio.com/index.php/problems/index`?

Comment: I've tested and it works!! `Hello, I am making some first content here.

...`

Comment: @rrrony yeah that works, but it is the same as just going to http://www.problemio.com/index.php and it doesn't show any sign of the view I created.  Totally confused what is supposed to happen.

Comment: can you paste the exact error it shows? May be you didn't change the class name in controller from Postscontroller to ProblemsController!!

Comment: There is no error - just a page not found.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you type:

http://www.problemio.com/index.php/problems/index

UPDATING...

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that it shows exactly the same thing as http://www.problemio.com/index.php and I don't know why the view is not being displayed, and the url so "uglified"

Comment: Where should I add those mod redirects? In the root .httaccess file? Also, what should I change the /config/routes.php default page to? I mean...I still want the root page to be www.problemio.com

Comment: Whats CI 1.3? :) You mean the cakephp version? Yeah something like that :)