# Can't see view in my CakePHP setup

Tags: php, cakephp

I made a view under /app_root/cakephp/app/views/problems/index.ctp and I am trying to get to a url where I can render it.

I also have an index.php at my site's root directory, and for some reason when I try to go to a url like http://www.mysite.com/index.php/problems/index I actually get the content from the index.php in the root, and not the view.

How should I set things up, or have the url path so that I can get to a url to see my view?

Here is my problems_controller.php

```
<?php

class ProblemsController extends AppController
{
    var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
    var $name = 'Problems';

    function index()
    {
        $this->set('problems', $this->Problem->find('all'));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP installation seems to be not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478733/cakephp-installation-seems-to-be-not-working)

Comment: Please don't close this. I am encountering a different issue than that question.

Comment: Did you create a ProblemsController? Views are not accessible via url, they are rendered by controller actions.

Comment: @dhofstet Yes, mine is called problems_controller.php and I am going to edit my question to post the code there.

Comment: Ok, and where does the DocumentRoot of Apache point to? To /path_to_your_project/app/webroot?

Comment: It points to /application_home where the original index.php is

Comment: Should it point to the cakephp setup root?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "cakephp setup root", but at least in a production setup it should point to app/webroot (see http://book.cakephp.org/view/914/Production)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3632/discussion-between-genadinik-and-dhofstet)

Answer (score 0):

If you could see the www.mysite.com when you installed cake and gave you no warnings or just security warnings you are ok. But if you didn't see it you should start the process again following the steps.

also

http://www.mysite.com/index.php/problems/index

Is NOT a url for a cakephp page the normal way (it may work though)

you should have something like

http://www.mysite.com/problems/index

cakephp url are domain/controller/action

maybe you don't have cake exactly there and have to use something like this

http://www.mysite.com/app/problems/index

OR

http://www.mysite.com/cakephp/app/problems/index

This two are if you copy the folders as the zip you download from the page. the last one may vary the cakephp part to cakephp-version or something like that. if you rename the app folder to something change it accordly. you can simplify this last two urls by doing some configurations ;) remember where you did the test of the cakephp when you install it.